# Jest does not recognize calls on spies in promise

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to test a method that calls a function in a promise.

**article-api.js** (simplified)

```
articleMiddleware(next) {
    return fetch(articleApiListUrl, { headers, method, body })
        .then(() => next({ some: 'data'}));

}
```

*This is a simplified version of `article-api.js`, full code can be seen here:*
https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/7bd9cce28d3a3b905fb8a408b37de3a9

I want to see if `next` has been called with `{ some: 'data'}`. I use [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) to mock my fetch request

**article-api.spec.js** (simplified)

```
describe('article api middleware', () => {

    it('creates ARTICLE_SUCCESS when fetching an article has been done', () => {
        fetchMock.post('*', { some: 'data' });
        return articleMiddleware(next)
            .then(expect(next).toBeCalledWith({ some: 'data' }))
            .then(() => fetchMock.restore());

    });

});
```

*This is a simplified version of `article-api.spec.js`, full code can be seen here:*
https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/178f591f516fe13c24fb0a4f02c4676c

What I get though is

> Expected mock function to have been last called with:
>        [{ some: 'data' }]
>      But it was not called.

If you view the full code in the two gists you'll find my code is a little bit different, the error messag there is

> ```
> expect(received).toBe(expected)
>
> Expected value to be (using ===):
>   2
> Received:
>   1
> ```

This is because of `next(action)` in line 17 in the first gist calls `next` (syncroneously) but the `next` inside the promise never gets called.

Comment: Are you sure that promise is not failing somewhere in the chain?

Comment: Yes, in the full version of my file to test https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/7bd9cce28d3a3b905fb8a408b37de3a9 I do a `console.log` in a `then` of a promise and that gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution only using `"jest": "^24.8.0"`, no need to use `fetch-mock`, you can mock it manually by yourself.

`article-api.js`:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function articleMiddleware(next) {
  const articleApiListUrl = 'https://github.com/mrdulin';
  const headers = {};
  const method = 'get';
  const body = {};

  return fetch(articleApiListUrl, { headers, method, body }).then(() => next({ some: 'data' }));
}

exports.articleMiddleware = articleMiddleware;
```

`article-api.spec.js`:

```js
jest.mock('node-fetch');

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { articleMiddleware } = require('./article-api');

describe('articleMiddleware', () => {
  it('t1', async () => {
    fetch.mockResolvedValueOnce({});
    const next = jest.fn();
    await articleMiddleware(next);
    expect(fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://github.com/mrdulin', { headers: {}, method: 'get', body: {} });
    expect(next).toBeCalledWith({ some: 'data' });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/42676657/article-api.spec.js
  articleMiddleware
    ✓ t1 (9ms)

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 article-api.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.131s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/42676657